# Bitcoin cash command line tools?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, blockchain-fork, bitcoin-cash

How can I use Bitcoin cash from the command line? In my understanding, even standard `bitcoind` and `bitcoin-cli` should work fine with it because the only blockchain was changed.

But may be there are any special tools/flags? Can you give some dead simple example, e.g. adding the new address to account and checking it's balance? With Bitcoin and `bitcoind` it can be done with 3 lines of code:

```
$ bitcoind -daemon
Bitcoin server starting
$ bitcoin-cli getnewaddress pavlovdog
1PB8NHbSG3CgvpzSMrvdeeAKaojZBXrwb # I've sent to this address 0.0001 BTC
$ bitcoin-cli getbalance pavlovdog
0.00010000
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You want to download the Bitcoin ABC client, then move your existing bitcoin directory (~/.bitcoin in Linux) or understand that you are going to modify that bitcoin data to go down the Bitcoin Cash fork.

You can use those same CLI coins just want to use the ABC client or any other client on the Bitcoin Cash side of the split.